# Tagged text (much like the tagged equation)

Tags: latex

I know how to introduce a tagged equation:

```
\begin{equation}
    \tag{P}
    x = 1 + 2 
\end{equation}
```

Is there a simple way to achieve the same but with the regular text instead of math formulas. Mainly I'd like to have the same layout and the tag. Something like

```
\begin{equation}
    \tag{P}
    \text{some text}
\end{equation}
```

is not what I need because in this case there are no line breaks in case if the text is large enough.

Comment: Do you need to cross-reference these tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have line breaks with your approach if you add something like a parbox or minipage:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fleqnon}{\@fleqntrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
{\fleqnon\begin{equation}
    \tag{P}
    \text{\parbox{.91\textwidth}{\lipsum[2]}}
    \label{foo}
\end{equation}}

\lipsum[1]

\ref{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]